# PHP — Why does my loop keep overwriting my data?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

This function is intentionally self-referential. I'm looping through an associative array, looking for all instances where a key-value pair matches the desired values. When I look at a value, if it's an array, I look inside.

If a match is found, the array skips forward to the next key-value pair which is where the data I'm interested in is located. I add that data to `$array_of_images` successfully.

When it checks every other key-value pair yielding an array, it overwrites `$array_of_images` with null rather than ignoring it, as I'd expect.

What am I doing wrong? Please and thank you.

```
public static function checkArrayItems($item,$key,$val)
    {
        $array_of_images = [];
        foreach ( $item as $k => $v )
        {
            if ( $k === $key && $v === $val )
            {
                $details = next($item);
                $array_of_images[] = $details;
                next($item);
            }
            else if ( is_array($v) ) self::checkArrayItems($v,$key,$val);
        }
        return $array_of_images;
    }
```

Comment: When you make the recursive call you don't do anything with the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

This is so called *recursive* function, in your case you are simply not catching the result of recursive calls.

```
public static function checkArrayItems($item,$key,$val)
{
    $array_of_images = [];
    foreach ( $item as $k => $v )
    {
        if ( $k === $key && $v === $val )
        {
            $details = next($item);
            $array_of_images[] = $details;
            next($item);
        }
        else if ( is_array($v) )
            $array_of_images = array_merge($array_of_images, self::checkArrayItems($v,$key,$val));
    }
    return $array_of_images;
}
```